# How to make any sans-serif glyph "touch" left border of a container div?

Tags: html, css, typography

I am facing a problem with headings when using sans-serif fonts. Most of the glyphs do not "touch" left border of a containing div in sans-serif fonts, the bigger the font the more apparent it becomes. Hence the header seems not aligned with the following regular text.

Here is a sample code:

```css
h1 {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 72px;
        font-weight: lighter;
    }
    
    .container {
        border-left: 1px solid;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>F glyph</h1>
    <h1>T glyph</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mishamsk/j73wwqa5/

Is there any workaround?

Comment: I wouldn't bother frankly. One option would be to add some negative `text-indent` but, as the difference between _F_ and _T_ character shows, that would be dependent on the text of your header.

Comment: Yeah, seems so. I am building a wordpress theme so there is no way to know the header text upfront. I am so baffled I had not noticed it before on the web;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this with CSS except by experimentally adjusting the placement, in a manner that is inevitably dependent on the character and the font family, weight, and style. It is also dependent on the font size, but this can be handled using the `em` unit. For the example given, and using specifically Arial (note that `sans-serif` maps to a system-dependent default font), the following would work—but different values would be needed for other characters than “F” and for other fonts:

```css
h1 {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 72px;
        font-weight: lighter;
    }
    
    .container {
        border-left: 1px solid;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1 style="text-indent: -0.06em">F glyph</h1>
    <h1>T glyph</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

I have set the value so that the “F” is roughly as close to the left border as the “T”, which does not quite touch it.

Situations like these are among the few where inline style sheets, in `style` elements, make sense, since the rules very much relate to the specific element.

Typesetting programs may have tools for adjustments that align *glyphs* to the left or right boundary of a text block. They known the properties of glyphs. But CSS has no tools for the purpose; it does not “know” what a glyph looks like and what its dimensions are.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for some magical solution. Too bad there is none.